# Laravel Eloquent Many to Many [Edit]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have Many-Many tables of users and tasks and user_task. That users are able to be assigned multiple tasks.

```
**User model:** 
public function tasks() { 
  return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'user_task', 'user_uuid', 'task_uuid'); 
} 

**Task Model:** 
public function users() { 
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_task', 'task_uuid', 'user_uuid'); 
} 

**Controller:** 
public function store(Request $request) { 
  $user = auth()->user(); 
  $tasks_uuid = $request->tasks; 
  $user->tasks()->sync($tasks_uuid); 
  return response()->json(['message' => 'Submit'], 200); 
}
```

But after a successful store, I expect user_uuid but it stores id of user instead. [image]

Comment: can a task belong to multiple users? if not then `tasks` should have a `user_id` field as it would belong to users and there wouldn't be a pivot table at all

Comment: yes, one task can be assigned to multiple user.

Comment: the `belongsToMany` method call can take more arguments than 4 ... the fifth argument is the 'parentKey' ... if you don't pass the key you want here it will just use the Model's primary key by default, so you will need to pass the fifth argument as `uuid` if you want to override that and use that for the relationship

Answer (score 1):

Laravel convention presumes that the primary key name is 'id' if you did not follow that, you should pass the primary key name in your relation ...

[belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_belongsToMany) relation definition:

> BelongsToMany belongsToMany(string $related, string|null $table =
> null, string|null $foreignPivotKey = null, string|null
> $relatedPivotKey = null, string|null $parentKey = null, string|null
> $relatedKey = null, string|null $relation = null)

for your case your relation should be:

```
**User model:** 
public function tasks() { 
  return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'user_task', 'user_uuid', 'task_uuid','user_uuid','task_uuid'); 
} 

**Task Model:** 
public function users() { 
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_task', 'task_uuid', 'user_uuid','task_uuid','user_uuid'); 
}
```